# Android emulator doesn't start anymore

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm running on OSX Mountain Lion. I recently installed the latest version of Eclipse and the Android SDK from Eclipse. I updated the SDK through Eclipse as well, downloading everything in the Extras, Android 2.2 (API 8), Android 4.1.2 (API 16) and the Tools folder.

Finally I could run the emulator by creating a device but it was very slow (I have 250gb ssd hard drive + 16gb RAM), I couldn't even run the application I had. I tried to modify some options of the emulator and now apparently I can't run anything anymore. As soon as I try to run a program (Hello World) I get the following infamous Mac OSX error:

`emulator-arm quit unexpectedly.`

The console output for Eclipse is the following:

```
[2012-10-19 15:46:06 - test] Android Launch!
[2012-10-19 15:46:06 - test] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-19 15:46:06 - test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-19 15:46:06 - test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'test'
[2012-10-19 15:46:06 - test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'test'
```

I tried to reset things as they were before as well as creating a new emulator device. I tried to restart Eclipse and the machine itself but nothing. Apparently I can't run any Android application anymore.

Does somebody has some idea? I read on some similar thread to use `adb` to restart the thing, but apparently I can't get that running as well. By doing `./adb shell` I get `error: device not found`. Do you have any idea about what can I do to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried building "simple" avds such as  512 mb ram and say 1 gb sdcard.?

Comment: yes, the second device i built was exactly 512mb ram and 1gb sd card, nothing, same error.

Comment: Are you making and avd from virtual device manager in eclipse or command line

Comment: Virtual device manager from Eclipse, both the emulators.

Comment: go to command prompt and try doing emulator-arm -avd YOURAVDNAME -verbose

Comment: I don't have emulator-arm installed, where can I find it for OSX?

Comment: You could try with setting -verbose if you get any valuable info: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Comment: Another simple solution can be found here: [http://codeghost.co.uk/blog/2012/12/17/avd-crashes-on-launch-emulator64-arm-quit-unexpectedly](http://codeghost.co.uk/blog/2012/12/17/avd-crashes-on-launch-emulator64-arm-quit-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your android sdk. In eclipse it should be an button next to the open avd manager button. or from command line try android update sdk --no-ui. 
the following link should help scroll down to see how to update. https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Installing+and+Updating+Android+SDK

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to update via Terminal, apparently it's installing something. As I mentioned in the question, I already updated through the Android SDK Manager in Eclipse and all the packages look installed. I'll let you know if after the Terminal update something works or not.

Comment: when updating through the android sdk manager make sure you select all options. If you select all there are few proprietary  packages which you need user login for those if you cancel it proceeds to next one.Once you complete update run adb list targets. and dont forget to accept the answer at last

Comment: Thanks, updating via terminal was the thing!

Comment: The link for this answer is no longer working. In future your answer should be able to still answer the question without a link. In this case the accepted answer is now completely useless.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is essentially the AVD manager can’t re-open a virtual device that was on a second monitor on a Mac. The work around is to edit the following file

```
~/.android/avd/.avd/emulator-user.ini
```

(depending on your system, this may be at ~/.android/avd/Default.avd/emulator-user.ini too)

and change the window.x and window.y entries to

```
window.x=0
window.y=0
```

Source: http://timvoet.com/2013/01/04/avd-emulator-crashes-on-mac/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged. Please consider adding a synopsis of the referenced article to your answer, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: The directory is different on my system 10.9, Android Studio 2.3.6, it's now .android/avd/Default.avd. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Note that the path of your emulator-user.ini file may be specific to the OS version. In OS X v10.9, it's `~/.android/avd/<name-of-avd>.avd/emulator-user.ini`

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I noticed that running VirtualBox seems to get a lock on HAX which prevents android emulator window from ever opening. Closing VirtualBox seems to release the lock and everything works again.

Comment: I've had this same issue. I had Vagrant (Laravel Homestead) running in background and could not get any Android emulators running on my Mac 'til I halted the Vagrant machines.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but the suggested ideas didn't solve my problem, after swearing and waving my fist at the Gods, I worked backwards to when it WAS working, and decided to change my SDK Tools version back from the Android SDK Tools RC 22.6 to Android SDK Tools 22.3.

Start up emulator64-x86 4.4.2 intel atom instance and low and behold it works again.

2 valuable hours later... Gotta love working with Android. :O

Moral of the story don't use the Preview Channel Releases.